# Help with generalizing a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following when $\alpha$ is independent of $n$

$$
Q_{n+1}=Q_n + \alpha[R_n-Q_n]
$$
$$
=\alpha R_n + (1-\alpha)Q_n
$$
$$
=\alpha R_n + (1-\alpha)[\alpha R_{n-1} + (1-\alpha)^2Q_{n-1}]
$$
$$
=\alpha R_n + (1-\alpha)\alpha R_{n-1}+(1-\alpha)^2\alpha R_{n-2} + ... +(1-\alpha)^{n-1}\alpha R_1 + (1-\alpha)Q_1
$$
$$
=(1-\alpha)^n Q_1+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha (1-\alpha)^{n-i}R_i
$$

My task is to repeat in a similar manner as the above but when $\alpha$ is is dependent on $n$ and determine the $weighting$ on each $R$. I was able to get a form similar to above however I am unsure as to the correctness of the form as it seems very messy.

$$
Q_{n+1}=Q_n + \alpha_n[R_n-Q_n]
$$
$$
=\alpha_n R_n + (1-\alpha_n)Q_n
$$
$$
=\alpha_n R_n + (1-\alpha_n)[\alpha_{n-1}R_{n-1}+(1-\alpha_{n-1})Q_{n-1}]
$$
$$
=\alpha_n R_n + (1-\alpha_n)\alpha_{n-1}R_{n-1}+(1-\alpha_n)(1-\alpha_{n-1})Q_{n-1}
$$
$$
=\alpha_n R_n + (1-\alpha_n)\alpha_{n-1}R_{n-1}+(1-\alpha_n)(1-\alpha_{n-1})\alpha_{n-2}R_{n-2}+...+R_1\alpha_1\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}(1-\alpha_i)+Q_1\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\alpha_i)
$$
$$
=Q_1\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\alpha_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n R_i\alpha_i\prod_{j=1}^{n-i}(1-\alpha_{j+1})
$$

The first sort of problem with the above result is the product in the $R$ expression can have bounds like $\prod_{j=1}^{0}$ which I then just treat as 1, is this acceptable? For instance, let $n=1$
$$
Q_2=Q_1\prod_{i=1}^1(1-\alpha_i)+\sum_{i=1}^1 R_i\alpha_i\prod_{j=1}^{1-i}(1-\alpha_{j+1})
$$
$$
Q_2=Q_1(1-\alpha_1)+R_1\alpha_1\prod_{j=1}^{0}(1-\alpha_{j+1})
$$
$$
Q_2=Q_1(1-\alpha_1)+R_1\alpha_1
$$

Which doesn't seem right to me. Can someone let me know if this working out is correct? Also would the $weighting$ for $R_i$ be $\alpha_i\prod_{j=1}^{n-i}(1-\alpha_{j+1})$?

Thanks for any help